# HQL multiple right joins with optional @ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate, hql, jpql

I have a data model like the following:

```
Singer {}

Concert {
  @ManyToOne
  Singer singer;
}

Fan {
  @ManyToOne
  Singer singer;
}
```

Now I would like to get a list of all combinations of singers, their concerts and fans (this is just an example, of course). I want all singers, even if they don‘t have concerts or fans. I tried it like this in HQL:

```
SELECT s, c, f FROM Concert c RIGHT JOIN c.singer s, Fan f RIGHT JOIN f.singer s1 WHERE s=s1
```

However, when a singer has no fans or concerts, he is not returned by this query since the cross product with the empty collection of fans seems to be built before the fans are right-joined with the singers.

How can I solve that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i think that you should face this problem by changing your approach. Try to use Entity relationship,something like this:

```java
Singer {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "singer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<Concert> concerts;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "singer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<Fan> fans;
}
```

And, your HQL changes to:

```sql
select s from Singer s 
    join fetch s.concerts 
    join fetch s.fans
```

When you search for a Singer, hibernate will fetch `fans` and `concerts` related to the singer. Empty Sets will be instantiated if the Singer has no data related.